# replacing image in file manager does not replace the image in app

Tags: image, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I uploaded an image on firebase storage. and to access said image on my flutter app, I first download it to the device and then use FileImage to display the image. However, if the image is changed, it still displays the previous one... Here's my code

```
  var error;
  Future getImage() async {
    try {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );
      await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(userMap['uid'])
          .putFile(image)
          .onComplete;

      await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(userMap['uid'])
          .writeToFile(File(path))
          .future;
      setState(() {
        profile = FileImage(File(path));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }
  }
```

The following code displays the image...

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
     getImage();
   },
   child: CircleAvatar(
     child: Icon(
     Icons.add_a_photo,
     color: color2.withOpacity(0.5),
     ),
     radius: widget.height * 0.05,
     backgroundColor: color3,
     backgroundImage: profile,
  ),
),
```

please help

Comment: Flutter has an in-memory image cache.  You would need to use [`imageCache.clear()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache/clear.html) or [`imageCache.evict()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache/evict.html) first to re-download the image.

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend you another way to solve your issue.

First thing, you don't need to use FileImage because it's very difficult control you cache
with it.

Try the next code:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File image) async {
  var reference = FirebaseStorage.insance.ref().child(userMap['uid']);
  var uploadTask = reference.putFile(image); // you can just put your file like that
  var snapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
  var location = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL(); // and get url with it with this code
  return location.toString()
}

Future getImage() async {
  try {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    profile = await uploadImage(image)
    setState((){});
  }
  catch (e) {
    error = e;
  }
}
```

after you get your url address with uploadImage, please use library: https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image. It's perfect for work with images.

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
     getImage();
   },
   child: CircleAvatar(
     child: Icon(
     Icons.add_a_photo,
     color: color2.withOpacity(0.5),
     ),
     radius: widget.height * 0.05,
     backgroundColor: color3,
     backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
        imageUrl: profile,
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
  ),
),
```